# Hide an UIImageView on UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I'm new to swift and I'm working on a project where I have a custom UITableViewCell (with a custom cell class) and inside that cell I have a UIImageView with an icon where I wants it to appear when a particular cell is selected. Though the icon appears once a cell is selected I wants to make sure it disappears once a new row is selected. But as of now I'm unable to make the icon disappear once a new row is been selected. How would I do this ? The code as bellow

```
  func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! MyAudiosTableViewCell
        cell.speakerImageView.isHidden = true


        return cell

    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! MyAudiosTableViewCell

        cell.speakerImageView.isHidden = false
        self.audioPlayListTableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)


    }
```

Comment: no need to dequeue the cell in didSelectRowAt method

Comment: Then how should I access the element "speakerImageView" which I have as an outlet in my custom cell class

Comment: let selectedcell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! MyAudiosTableViewCell

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this properly you will need a bit more then it seems. The table view reuses cells so you need to retain the state of the selected cell.

**The solution first:**

Once a cell is selected you need to save the selected index. Then you need to reload the table view and use the selected index in the cell for row at index path:

```
var selectedIndexPath: IndexPath?
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! MyAudiosTableViewCell

    // Check if cell needs to be selected
    if let selectedIndexPath = selectedIndexPath, indexPath.row == selectedIndexPath.row && indexPath.section == selectedIndexPath.section {
        cell.speakerImageView.isHidden = false
    } else {
        cell.speakerImageView.isHidden = true
    }

    return cell

}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if let selectedIndexPath = selectedIndexPath, indexPath.row == selectedIndexPath.row && indexPath.section == selectedIndexPath.section {
        // The same cell is selected again, deselect it. Or do nothing to disable deselection
        self.selectedIndexPath = nil
    } else {
        self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath
    }

    tableView.reloadData() // We need to call this so the visible cells are updated

    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

**So to explain a bit on it:**

The table view will dequeue cells when it can. That means it will reuse the same cell for another index path if the previous index path is no longer visible. This is the main reason why you need to save the state of the selection beyond putting it on the table view cell.

So in your case you have no reference to which cell should deselect which could be done by saving the cell itself as a property instead of the selected index path. But that produces another issue where the saved cell actually represents another index path since it has been reused.

So the only thing that makes sense is to save the index path or the object that needs to be selected. You then need to reload the table view but do not worry about that as the reloaded cells are only those visible.

Comment: Don't you think you in `cellForRowAt` you need to write just like this `cell.speakerImageView.isHidden = self.seletedIndexPath != indexPath` No need for if condition.

Comment: in the didSelectRowAt method it wont let  selectedIndexPath to be assigned as nil. what should i do

Comment: Well apart from the selected index path being optional it should work. But the index path structure is so weird that I do not dare doing that. I rather compare both of the values.

Comment: Sorry, will fix it to self.selectedIndexPath

Comment: I'm sorry I dont understand why still throws an error saying "cannot assigned to value 'selectedIndexPath' is a let constant.

Comment: Try copying the code again. I just did the same and it compiles.

Answer (score 0):

when you select new row reload the tableView first then show the image view

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! MyAudiosTableViewCell
        cell.speakerImageView.isHidden = true


        return cell

    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
      tableView.tableView.reloadData()
       let selectedcell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! MyAudiosTableViewCell

        selectedcell.speakerImageView.isHidden = false
        self.audioPlayListTableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

    }
```

Comment: Can you explain why are you reloading tableview in `didSelectRow`?

Comment: This will not work if the table view is scrolled till the point where the cell with the visible image view is reused and then scrolled back to the one that is supposed to be selected. Then all will have hidden view again.

Comment: Exactly. Because of that the row doesnt get select at all. what should I do

Comment: reloading because once table view reloaded the imageView of all cell hide after this we show the selected cell 's image

Comment: With this code my row does not get select at all. My requirement is to make sure the image appears once a row been selected and disappears the image in the old row once a new row been selected. Basically the image appears  only in the currently selected row. How could I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

After hours of trying managed to solve this

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! MyAudiosTableViewCell

            if let selectedIndexPath = selectedIndexPath, indexPath.row == selectedIndexPath.row && indexPath.section == selectedIndexPath.section {
                cell.speakerImageView.isHidden = false
            } else {
                cell.speakerImageView.isHidden = true
            }

            return cell

        }
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
           let selectedcell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! MyAudiosTableViewCell

            if(selectedIndexPath != nil){
                let previousCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: selectedIndexPath!) as! MyAudiosTableViewCell
                previousCell.speakerImageView.isHidden = true
            }

            selectedcell.speakerImageView.isHidden = false

            if let selectedPath = selectedIndexPath, indexPath.row == selectedIndexPath?.row && indexPath.section == selectedIndexPath?.section {
                selectedIndexPath = selectedPath

            } else {
                selectedIndexPath = indexPath
            }

        }
```